# Trying to issue a command through a Launcher

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, command-line, minecraft

So I am attempting to get a one click minecraft server. I have all the code, and all the programs, but cannot for the life of me work out why this won't work.

So I have a launcher with this as the execute line:

`Exec=gnome-terminal --command=cd "/minecraft/server" && java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -jar craftbukkit.jar"`

It opens up gnome terminal and gives me this error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "cd"(No such file or directory)
```

I have tried so many different variables, but none of them seem to work. If you could give me an example to one that will work, and why this isn't working that would be great.

Comment: Try it as: `Exec=gnome-terminal --command='cd "/minecraft/server" && java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -jar craftbukkit.jar`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. If I just put one ' at the beginning of the command= it doesn't even start terminal, and if I put one at the beginning and end it gives the same error..

Comment: Hmm, it should. Try this: `Exec=gnome-terminal --command='cd /minecraft/server && java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -jar craftbukkit.jar` without the parenthesis around the path to the server.

Comment: Terminal doesn't even open.. :/ This has been frustrating me for the last few days, why is it so complicated? Haha. One thing I liked about Command Prompt on Windows was you could just make a batch file with a list of commands and it would run them all. This is just complicated. ._.

Comment: Hmm. That is really strange. I will try posting it in chat and see if that generates any attention.

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cd /minecraft/server; java -Xmx768M -Xms768M -jar craftbukkit.jar; exec $SHELL"
```

Comment: You are a beautiful human being. Works perfectly. Could you explain what you added and why it works? Thank you! :)